# How to monkey-patch code that gets auto-loaded in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm monkey-patching a Rails engine with something like:

```
SomeClass.class_eval do
  # ...
end
```

The first time I hit the web site, on development mode at least, it works, but the second time it's like my patch never existed. I presume it's Rails auto-reloading the engine (which is installed in vendor/) and not reloading my code. This is Rails 2.3.

Any ideas how to do it so that my code also gets reloaded?

Comment: I hit a similar problem once and the only way I could fix it was by running rails in production mode on my dev machine :(. I'm also interested on this.

Comment: @egarcia: ouch, I hope we can find a better solution this time.

Comment: how do you run your code, is it webbrick, mongrel or passenger ? please post rails and server versions.

Answer (score 29):

EDIT: This solution only works for Rails 3+ since it's dependent on some functionality in Rails::Railtie. Put this code in an initializer.

This question is quite old, but here's a solution I found:

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  SomeClass.class_eval do
    # ...
  end
end
```

This forces Rails to reload the class on every request in development mode, but only once in production.

Comment: Working for me in Rails 5 as well.

Comment: Working for me in Rails 7 as well. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

I just wrote my first monkey-patch, and so needed to come up with a set of conventions around it.  Here's what I came up with:

1. Place your extensions under `lib/ext/`.  *(Suggested by veteran workmad3 in #rubyonrails IRC room.)*  In my case, I'm adding a method to the `Mail::Message` class (from the `mail` gem, used by ActionMailer), so I created:

   `/lib/ext/mail/message.rb`
2. Open the class or module and add your code:

   `module Mail
     class Message
       def to_is_phone?
         !!(self.to.first =~ /^\+1\d{10}$/)
       end
     end
   end`
3. Create an initalizer to load all your monkey-patches.  Rails will autoload a file when a constant is referenced, but since you're adding methods to existing classes/modules rather than defining new ones, that won't work, so you have to manually require all your monkey-patches.  So I created:

   `/config/initializers/monkey_patches.rb`

   Which contains:

   `require 'ext/mail/message'`

Comment: Note that I'm currently using Rails 4.1, but I think this should work in older versions as well.

Comment: `monkey_patches.rb`can instead be `Dir[Rails.root.join('lib/ext/*.rb')].each { |file| require file }` and all monkey patches will be picked up.

Comment: @DanKohn double asterisk ftw! :) ``Dir[Rails.root.join('lib/ext/**/*.rb')].each { |file| require file }``

Answer (score 5):

If you place the patch in any .rb file inside /config/initializers, it should work.

Comment: what's the difference with using class_eval and to_prepare?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to hook into the reloading mechanism of Rails 2.x.
What you could do, is place your patch somewhere in the app or lib directory. (`lib/core_ext` is probably the preferred location). Then add the directory to the autoload_paths in your config.

You might also need to open the class, rather than using class_eval.

Comment: The monkey-patch is already on lib/ which is already on the autoload_paths on Rails 2. I'm not sure why, but opening the class with the class keyword instead of class_eval results into an error, an exception thrown later on.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but I found that if I put this kind of code at the bottom of environments.rb it always guaranteed correct load-order on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how this gem handles "decorating" aka monkey patching something in an engine or vice versa:

https://github.com/EPI-USE-Labs/activesupport-decorators